# Overloading members from template class on bool value

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, metaprogramming, type-traits

I'm trying to avoid concepts on the master branch of my projects, so I need some kind of alternative with `type_trait`:

I need a class whom some few functions will change depending on the `bool` value.

Someone already suggest me to split my class, but this case won't make sense here. For some context it's a pool where remove function and some others will change if the object type of the pool can be shared or not.

So I tried to use `std::enable_if`, but there are still some errors (**I want the declaration and the implementation to be separate**).

```
#include  <type_traits>

template < typename Object, bool Shared = false >
class Foo {

  template < bool S = Shared, typename std::enable_if<S>::type* = nullptr >
  void   bar();

  template < bool S = Shared, typename std::enable_if<!S>::type* = nullptr >
  void   bar();
};

template < typename Object,
           bool Shared >
template < bool S, typename std::enable_if<S>::type* = nullptr >
void   Foo<Object, Shared>::bar() {
    //do something
}


template < typename Object,
           bool Shared >
template < bool S, typename std::enable_if<!S>::type* = nullptr >
void   Foo<Object, Shared>::bar() {
  //do nothing
}

int main() {

  Foo<int> test;
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
Test3.cpp:16:33: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing ‘void Foo<Object, Shared>::bar()’
 void   Foo<Object, Shared>::bar() {
                                 ^
Test3.cpp:24:33: error: default argument for template parameter for class enclosing ‘void Foo<Object, Shared>::bar()’
 void   Foo<Object, Shared>::bar() {
```

EDIT: Removed copy/paste error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.The qualification of class name (i.e. `Foo<Object, Shared>::`) should be deleted for member function declaration **inside** the class definition.

2.[Default template arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Default_template_arguments) are not allowed for out-of-class definition of member templates, just remove them.

> Default parameters are not allowed
>
> - in the out-of-class definition of a member template (they have to be
>     provided in the declaration inside the class body)

Then

```
template < typename Object, bool Shared = false >
class Foo {

  template < bool S = Shared, typename std::enable_if<S>::type* = nullptr >
  void  bar();

  template < bool S = Shared, typename std::enable_if<!S>::type* = nullptr >
  void  bar();
};

template < typename Object,
           bool Shared >
template < bool S, typename std::enable_if<S>::type*  >
void   Foo<Object, Shared>::bar() {
    //do something
}

template < typename Object,
           bool Shared >
template < bool S, typename std::enable_if<!S>::type* >
void   Foo<Object, Shared>::bar() {
  //do nothing
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/UHR94974)

Comment: I found something pretty cool : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXSsUqVSe2k

Answer (score 2):

As alternative, you might use tag-dispatching:

```
template <typename Object, bool Shared = false>
class Foo {
public:
    void bar() { bar(std::integral_constant<bool, Shared>{}); }

private:
    void bar(std::true_type);
    void bar(std::false_type);
};

template <typename Object, bool Shared>
void Foo<Object, Shared>::bar(std::true_type) { /**/ }

template <typename Object, bool Shared>
void Foo<Object, Shared>::bar(std::false_type) { /**/ }
```

Since C++17, you might use `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename Object, bool Shared = false>
class Foo {
public:
    void bar() {
        if constexpr (Shared) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

So each block is only available in the right version:

- so no runtime branch (I expect regular branch to be optimized anyway in your case)
- not chosen block may contain code valid only when that branch would be chosen (mostly useful when it depends of **type**).

And C++20 introduces `requires`:

```
template <typename Object, bool Shared = false>
class Foo {
public:
    void bar() requires(Shared) {
        // ...
    }
    void bar() requires(!Shared) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code once fixed (minimal, working example):

```
#include  <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template < typename Object, bool Shared = false >
class Foo {
public:
    template < bool S = Shared, typename std::enable_if<S>::type* = nullptr >
    void bar();

    template < bool S = Shared, typename std::enable_if<!S>::type* = nullptr >
    void bar();
};

template < typename Object, bool Shared >
template < bool S, typename std::enable_if<S>::type*>
void  Foo<Object, Shared>::bar() {
    std::cout << "do something" << std::endl;
}

template < typename Object, bool Shared >
template < bool S, typename std::enable_if<!S>::type*>
void Foo<Object, Shared>::bar() {
    std::cout << "do nothing" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Foo<int> test;
    test.bar<>();
    test.bar<true>();
    return 0;
}
```

It was a problem of extra qualifiers and default parameters not to be repeated in out of class definitions.

Comment: Thanks! I feel bad to have asked this now ^^ Mostly because I made an error with copy/paste for the minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

As extra note, that is a much more cleaner solution:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<bool b>
using allow_if = typename std::enable_if<b>::type;

template <typename Object, bool Shared = false>
class Foo {
public:
    template<bool S = Shared>
    allow_if<S> bar();

    template<bool S = Shared>
    allow_if<!S> bar();
};

template<typename Object, bool Shared>
template<bool S>
allow_if<S> Foo<Object, Shared>::bar() {
    std::cout << "do something" << std::endl;
}

template<typename Object, bool Shared>
template<bool S>
allow_if<!S> Foo<Object, Shared>::bar() {
    std::cout << "do nothing" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Foo<int> test;
    test.bar<>();
    test.bar<true>();
    return 0;
}
```